# Android:How to calculate latitude and longitude of an image from (x,y) coordinates?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

How to calculate latitude and longitude  of a position or place in  an image(floor plan)  from (x,y) coordinates of the image if the 4 corners of image's latitude and longitude are known to us.

Answer (score 0):

The system is overspecified with positions for all four corners, so there are many possible functions for taking the fuzzyness into account. I would try bilinear interpolation.

Comment: The formula for bilinear interpolation is right on the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation. You will want to run it twice, once to get the X coordinate and once to get the Y coordinate. So you would put all the known X coordinates in the corners and run the interpolation to get the estimated X for the point. Then repeat for Y.

Comment: id doesn't give correct  data as lat and long are not linear distributed

Comment: I was thinking you intend to use this for small areas that are approximately planar. If you have a map of the globe you are working with, then you need to worry about the projection. What kind of projection does you image use?

Comment: its can  works for a small area.but it can't be use for a big area......I am not using any projection but i have 4 corners lat and long.......and i have to calc images's inbetween lat and long where user touches......;

Comment: Well, it sounds like the projection function should be known, but I suppose your code could try to match different projection functions against the data for the four corners to see which it is. Sounds like you have some involved math to do, you ought to ask on the math site.